# Python Beginner Question: How to use for/while loop to solve this question?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, while-loop, slice

Situation:

- let the user enter a full name
- with space to separate
- Can show "Hi" before each "sub-name"

Example:

- User entered: Zoe Xander Young
- Expected result:
  Hi Zoe
  Hi Xander
  Hi Young

My question:

How to solve this problem by Python? (Because I'm learning Python and this exercise got from a book)

I'm not sure whether I should indicate the index of space and then slice the full name.

Here's what I did so far:

```
user_input = "name name name"

for i in range(len(user_input)):
    if user_input[i] == " ":
        index_space = i
        print(i)
        continue
    print(user_input[i], end = " ")
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint, you loop should start with `for name in user_input.split():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pytonic way of resolving the question with a `for loop`:

```py
user_input = "Zoe Xander Young"


for n in user_input.split():
    print('hi ' + n)
```

And here is an alternative method using `list comprehension`:

```py
user_input = "Zoe Xander Young"
[print('hi '+n) for n in user_input.split()]
```

For both of the above the output would be:

```
hi Zoe
hi Xander
hi Young
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Got lots of help from here (since this is my first question in Stackflow)